# How to extract data from table with some exceptions with selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, extract

I would like to extract all data from a table but not data which are underlined.

Here is a code which extract all data :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import numpy as np

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("enable-automation")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

url = 'https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-parme-inter-milan-rid1161129.html'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-default btn-xs btncote")]')))]

columns = 3
rows = int(len(odds)/columns)
odds = [float(i) for i in odds]
odds = np.array(odds)
odds = odds.reshape(rows, columns)

print(odds, '\n')
                
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Here is the output :

```
[[12.2   6.45  1.28]
 [12.    6.5   1.28]
 [12.    6.25  1.28]
 [12.5   6.5   1.25]
 [11.    6.1   1.28]
 [11.    5.75  1.28]
 [11.5   6.    1.25]
 [11.5   6.    1.25]
 [12.    6.    1.24]
 [11.5   6.    1.24]
 [ 9.5   5.3   1.26]
 [ 9.2   5.    1.27]]
```

My goal is to extract all data without the lines 6 and the last one because data are underlined.
Maybe you can help. Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using pandas `from_html` by using the `page_source` attribute on the driver to feed the html to it?

Comment: data on the table are not visible in  the page source

Comment: That explains this `odds = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class, "btn btn-default btn-xs btncote")]')))]`. Is it possible to see what values are underlined when looping through the elements in that line then exclude them?

Comment: you can see the underlined values on the url page : https://www.coteur.com/match/cotes-parme-inter-milan-rid1161129.html

Comment: the goal is to extract all odds from the table expect underlined values

Comment: Are the underlined values the ones in the blue infilled boxes or only with a blue border? I was looking at it and you might even beable to create a websocket connection to the site which will give the info possibly as json

Comment: I am speaking about the odds underlined which represent the bookmaker BWIN and VBET